Microsoft Word scales up the header image when printing for unknown reason
I've got a coworker finds when he prints on company letterhead, the header image is scaled up about 20% and is cut off on the right by the page margin and on the bottom by the main text of the document. It does not move in position, it just stretches towards the bottom right. On the print preview, it looks correct; only when printing does it scale up. It prints fine for everyone else, so I tried upgrading him to the newest version of Office, but the issue persists. It occurs on all printers, even print to PDF, so it's not printer specific. Computer had been restarted, updated, etc. to no avail. I find nothing in the settings that mentions header scaling, so I'm at a loss here.
Any advice on what to try next?

The interpretation/rendering of the printed page is largely done by the print driver, not the application.  If it scales well on screen, then it is the probably the print driver.  Word hands the print driver that exact device context to deal with and the printer needs to render it correctly 99% of the time.  Print to PDF.  Does the scaling still occur?

Are they printing a .doc? If so, ISTR there can be a problem related to an update a few years ago and that saving as .docx (and perhaps editing as needed before saving) then printing might solve this one.
